# Fuel Java SDK - Asynchronous Triggered Sends

Tags: trigger, marketing-cloud, fuel-sdk, asynchronous

Are asynchronous triggered send calls possible using Fuel Java SDK v1.0.3?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.  You will need to make sure you have a client secret and client ID.  I don't have a specific code example, unfortunately.

Comment: Hi. I am not able to modify the FromAddress using TriggeredSendDefinition . I have created a question here. If you could give me any hint It would be helpful. http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/140923/fuelsdk-unable-to-modify-html-body-subject-in-triggered-emails